# как сделать 2 header`a и footera`a на сайте Битрикс

Tags: php, html, битрикс

Вопрос в сабже.

Ситуация следующая.

На сайте есть несколько типов пользователей, клиент, дистриб, админ. Для неавторизованных пользователей нужно вывести одну шапку на сайте.  Для авторизованных другую, с разным функционалом для разных типов пользователей. Вопрос в том как это правильно сделать на Битрикс?

Я пытался с помощью API Битрикса получать Статус пользователя, залогинин ли он, и по условиям вывожу в файле header.php разные шапки.

Правильно ли это? Или же нужно создать несколько файлов header.php и подключать их для разных пользователей? Если да то как это правильно реализуется?

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться типовым функционалом. Сделать второй шаблон. Тот, который нужно выводить для неавторизованных оставить без условия, а второй шаблон выводить пользователям, которые принадлежат группе, в которую попадают пользователи при регистрации.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Лучше не пользоваться способом выше. Так как будет много шаблонов (в каждом шаблоне будут компоненты свои) и потом править их будет вызывать у Вас много проблем (так как во всех шаблонах будет разно содержимое). Лучще делать как вы делали до этого, ограничивать вывод по параметрам.

```
<?
   global $USER;
   if ($USER->IsAuthorized()) echo "Вы авторизованы!";
 ?>
```

Для вариаций вывода для других пользователей можете использовать проверку на группу  в которой находится пользователь. 
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cuser/getusergroup.php

Comment: Копировать шаблоны компонентов можно только в один шаблон, стили и скрипты можно тоже подтягивать с "главного". Второй можно использовать только для того, что нужно автору вопроса - подключение разных header и footer для разных групп пользователя. Зато потом, если понадобится добавить данный шаблон еще для одной группы, или отключить этот - не нужно будет копаться в коде, а достаточно пары кликов в админке.

Comment: Да но все подключать в шаблон default нужно иначе логика не сработа. Да и при добавлении нового шаблона все равно надо будет логику footer и header делать так что без кода не как @Юрий_Смирнов. По мне размножение шаблонов приводит к путанице, но тут уже кому как.